# Why does the dropdown menu become transparent when it overlaps the "container" div?

Tags: html, css, containers, overlap

The menu and everything works well on this trial site....but it acts weird when I click on the menu and the dropdown menu items appear.

Here is what I have put together so far: http://jsbin.com/tifuhute/36/

What happens is that everything that overlaps the "container" div becomes transparent and doesnt work as a menu when I hover over it. There is another container (a container called "otrosidiomas") that works just fine. So, this problem is beyond me.

Any ideas what I have done wrong?

Comment: Adding `#menu li { z-index:1; }` solves the problem it seems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because you have set `#column1` to position relative as well — and since it occurs further down in order compared to the sub-list, it will be stacked above the sub-list. One trick is to assign a non-zero z-index to the sub-list, say, 1, and that will fix the problem:

```
#menu ul li:hover ul {
    /* this is what makes the dropdown menu appear on hovering over it*/
    visibility: visible;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am wondering if I need to assign position to column1 and column2 at all? They are within another div to contain them. What do you think?

Comment: `position: relative` is only needed when (1) you have absolutely positioned descendants that rely on the parent's positioning on the page, or that (2) you are altering the position of said element yet wanting to keep the space it is taking up on the document (e.g. using `left: -10px`)